# Re-join cluster node after seed node got restarted

Tags: akka.net, akka-cluster

Let's imagine such scenario. I have a three nodes inside my akka cluster (node A,B,C). Each node is deployed to a different physical device inside a network.

All of those nodes are wrapped inside Topshelf windows services.

Node A is my seed node, the other ones are just simply 'worker' nodes with port specified.

When I run cluster and stop node (service) B or C and then restart them. Nodes are rejoining with no issues.

I'd like to ask whether it's possible to handle other scenario which will be. When I stop seed node (node A), the other nodes - services still running and then I restart node-service A - I'd like to make nodes B,C rejoin the cluster and make the whole eco system working again.

Is such scenario possible to implement? If yes then how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Akka.NET cluster any node can serve as a seed node for others as long as it's a part of the cluster. "Seeds" are just a configuration thing, so you can define a list of well-known node addresses you know, that are a part of the cluster.

Regarding your case, there are several solutions I can think of:

1. Quite common approach is to define more than one seed node in the configuration, so that your node doesn't serve as a single point of failure. As long as at least one of the configured seed nodes is alive, everything should work fine. Keep in mind, that the **seed nodes should be defined in each configuration in the exactly same order**.
2. If your "worker" nodes have statically assigned endpoints, they can be used as seed nodes as well.
3. Since you can initialize the cluster programmaticaly from code, you can also use 3rd party service as a node discovery service. You can use i.e. consul for that - I've started [a project](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akka.Cluster.Discovery), which gives such functionality. While it's not yet published, feel free to fork it or contribute, if it will help you.